# Does a response containing multiple json Values always have to be wrapped in an array in java?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I am trying to return a response from the back end using java where the response is a list of json values.

Is it possible to return the data in this format?

```
{"someKey": someValue},
{"someKey2": someValue},
{"someKey2": someValue}
```

I noticed that json values are always returned wrapped in an array like this

```
[
{"someKey": someValue},
{"someKey2": someValue},
{"someKey2": someValue}
]
```

I was asked to return the json data without being in an array and I am having trouble doing that. Is it even possible to return a list of json objects without being wrapped in an array? This is in java using the ObjectMapper class

Comment: The response should be a valid JSON, the first one is not a valid JSON.

Comment: What's the reason for the client wanting a non-array response? Do they really understand what they want?

Comment: Not sure about the reasoning, I was just told to do it and assumed it would be possible. After trying for a few hours I'm really thinking that it isn't possible beacuse it isn't even a valid JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have pointed out, a list of objects without the wrapping array.would be invalid JSON.

However, if you really must return that, you could arrange to get the JSON as a String, and then use String methods, of your choice (e.g. substring) to remove the square braces, and then return that. Ultimately, a JSON *is* a String.

Answer (score 1):

List of json objects not wrapped in an array `[]` is a invalid json format and will give you `error: multiple JSON root elements`

Possibly you can modify the result to this JSON format?

```
{
    "somekey": somevalue,
    "someKey2": someValue,
    "someKey3": someValue,
}
```